# add css class or id before a wordpress post/page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, linkify

i'm building a wordpress plugin, but to my plugin work needed a specific class in to html code (javascript linkify), but all templates themes are using different classes to formating the posts, for example:

```
<div class="post_content">
```

or

```
    <div class="content">
```

How i can embebed through my plugin my own specific div class to identify a post or page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the Codex for [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class). If the theme supports it (and every well written theme should support it) you can add your own classes to the body or post.

```
function my_plugin_class($classes) {
    if ( my_plugin_is_loaded() ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-plugin-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'my_plugin_class');    // add the class to the post content
add_filter('body_class', 'my_plugin_class');    // add the class to the body tag
```

You can differ between pages and posts with [`is_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) and [`is_single()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)

Comment: +1 Nice catch with `post_class()`, unfortunately we can never be sure if the theme author added it... Nonetheless, there's nothing much that can be done.

Comment: This work, but post_class add a name class to <article tag, not in a <div and you must take into account, +1 for your help

Comment: You can use too the_content filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

This filter permit do format to post and add anything, the_content make my day, thanks a lot to all for your Answers

Comment: That is my code right now using the_content filter:

function roll_over_link_class($content){
        $str = '<div class="rolloverlink">';
 $newcontent = $str.$content."</div>";
 return $newcontent;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'roll_over_link_class' );

Answer (score 0):

Use the body class filter. This will add a class to the body element.

E.g.

```
function wpse_plugin_add_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( my_plugin_conditional() ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-plugin-class';
    }

    return $classes; 
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_plugin_add_body_class' );
```

Be sure to change the conditional function to whatever you need. Then add your CSS like so:

```
.my-plugin-class #content {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```